# Add noise to traning data in Support vector machines

Tags: regression, svm, scikit-learn

I'm training a SVM regression using rbf kernals in sklearn. I have come across papers where it's suggested to add noise to the training data.

I would like to know the reason for adding noise to the training data? Does this noise help incorporating the outliers into the prediction?

What kind of effect does this noise have on the R2 coefficient and the Absolute relative error?

Comment: It would be helpful if you included references to the specific papers you're talking about. This is not a standard procedure in any field that I am aware of.